# Easy way to get from Kanchanaburi to Thong Pha Phum National Park?

Tags: transportation, thailand, remote-locations

I'm going to Thailand in July. I was browsing my Lonely Planet Thailand book as a prepatation, where I read about sleeping in treehouses in Thong Pha Phum National Park. But the book doesn't offer a lot of information about this place or getting there.

**Desired plan**

After a little bit of googling I've found out that I can take a bus from Bangkok to Kanchanaburi and take another bus there to Thong Pha Phum. I'm not sure but I think the treehouses are in the national park, which is still 35-40km further. Is it possible to take a cab to the national park (treehouses) and take one back the following day or is there other transportation I could use?

**Limited time**

I have limited time, so I can't be spending too much time there. I'll be in Bangkok for 5-6 days and I want to go to Kanchanaburi for 1 day and spend a night in such a treehouse if possible. But if it's too much of an effort or risk of wasting a few days, then I would only visit Kanchanaburi.

Does anyone have experience or knowledge about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The treehouses are run by the National Park and can be booked online, however getting and back again could be problematic, as you would need to prearrange round trip transport.  The village of Thong Pha Phum will have only few song teaws and motorcycle taxis.  I doubt you will find a taxi.

You are also going during rainy season, so clouds will obscure the views.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Unfortunately, I guess I'll best limit my trip and only visit Kanchanaburi and Erawan then. Thanks for the information though. The village probably doesn't have the same nice views and treehouses as the National Park I assume?